# find Math.min row value

Tags: javascript, csv

I want to find the row value of Math.min but I have no idea how to find this even though I have googled for a few days.

Can someone tell how to solve this issue?

```
function getDataPointsFromCSV(csv) {
            
            var dataPoints = csvLines =  [];   
            var price;                   
            var lowestv = Infinity; 
<!-- read csv file      
            csvLines = csv.split(/[\r?\n|\r|\n]+/);
<!-- read row 1-10          
            for (var i = 1; i <= 10; i++)
                if (csvLines[i].length > 0) {
<!-- read csv file              
                    points = csvLines[i].split(",");
<!-- read the data from points[4]=(column5)                 
                    price = points[4]
<!-- find the row number which store lowest value in a column               
                    lowestv = Math.min(price, lowestv) 
<!-- fault example; the value that I want to find is lowestv.length
                    for (var i = lowestv.length; i <= lowestv.length+10; i++)                   
             }                                          
        return dataPoints;
        }
```

Comment: I don't understand the question, can you clarify it please?

Comment: Is this the actual code, with the no-body for loop at the end and the HTML comments in the JS?

Comment: Why are you splitting on the `?` character?

Comment: The regexp should be `/[\r\n]+/`

Comment: JavaScript comments begin with `//`, not `<!--`

Comment: Yes this is the actual code. I am new to JavaScript. It's the function inside a html website. I want to get the lowestrow value in order to substitute the lowestrow value into `var i = lowestrow`

Comment: I don't know why did I split on the `?` character either. I copied it from canvasjs website.

Comment: Do someone know any ways that I can find the answer by myself?  I have googled honderds of websites but I still can't find the answer cause I have no idea how to combine them together.

Comment: Oh I have just discovered that this comment is fault. It should be `<!-- find lowest value in a coloumn  ` instead of  `<!-- find the row number which store lowest value in a coloumn  `

Comment: Yeah my question is not that clear. What I want to do is to find the row(number) that stored Math.min value in column 5(points[4]) of a csv file and sub this`lowestv.length` into other loop`for (var i = lowestv.length; i <= lowestv.length+10; i++)`

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `Math.min()`. Just test if `price` is lower than `lowestv`. If it is, save the price in `lowestv` and save the row in another variable.

```js
function getDataPointsFromCSV(csv) {
  csvLines = csv.split(/[\r\n]+/);
  let lowestv = Infinity;
  let lowestrow;
  csvLines.forEach(line => {
    row = line.split(',');
    price = row[4];
    if (price < lowestv) {
      lowestv = price;
      lowestrow = row;
    }
  })
  return lowestrow;
}
```

Comment: thankyou for helping me and I am trying to add loop in this function